# JavaFX: Tested/confirmed hardware (GPU) acceleration on Linux

Tags: linux, javafx-2, javafx-8

I would like to know if anyone managed to get a working version of JavaFX 2.2 or 8 on Linux with hardware acceleration.

Oracle provides a list of compatible GPUs: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html

But last time I've tried with a modern nVIDIA card and Ubuntu it reverted to software rendering.

Comment: I have been able to get hardware acceleration with the following configuration: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2 
Xorg 1.10.4, 
Gnome 2.28.2, 
nVidia Quadro 410 driver rev. 331.79

Comment: Managed to get it running with HW acceleration on a nVidia GeForce GTX 750.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 and nVidia GTX 750 Ti (Official drivers):

```
www@www-MS-7577:~$ java -Dprism.verbose=true -jar JavaFXApp.jar
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw
Using platform text rasterizer
Using java-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 16384
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
Non power of two texture support = true
Graphics Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       Renderer: GeForce GTX 750 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
        Version: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.46
 vsync: true vpipe: true
new alphas
QuantumRenderer: shutdown
```