# Use java to find GPU specifications on windows

Tags: java

I know that are many questions regarding of getting OS level information, I came through almost all of them, but I did not find something related to the gpu. I used System.getProperties, Runtime class and System.getenv.
Thank you!
Edited: I search for a windows solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26305209/2970947

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX: Tested/confirmed hardware (GPU) acceleration on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159317/javafx-tested-confirmed-hardware-gpu-acceleration-on-linux)

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mention that I search for a windows solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information

Comment: @Ramachandra Reddy I did not find something about gpu there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code :

```
String line;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET description");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
input.close();
```

Output on my computer:

> Description
>   Intel(R) HD Graphics 520

Windows commands are

```
wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET description
wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET adapterram
wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET driverversion
wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET pnpdeviceid
```